# XenCenter Client Logins

Tags: xenserver

Currently, I have a XenServer and XenCenter setup with my root account which allows me to manage all the VM's on the server.

I'd like to know if it is possible to create client accounts in XenServer which have permissions that are set so they can only manage 1 or 2 VM's instead of all the VM's on the server and the server itself.

So to clarify - I want to be able to create user accounts that do not have root privilages in XenServer so that other people can login and manage 1 or 2 VM's which are assigned to their account.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Looking at this: http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/XenCenter It seems that it is possible - "Role-based access control"

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is not possible with XenCenter although there is a web-based alternative from Citrix called **XenServer Self Service Virtual Appplaince**. It's a CentOS VM that allows you you to assign specific users access to VM console sessions along with other controls.

http://blogs.citrix.com/2010/10/06/xenserver-self-service-portal-up-and-running-in-5-mins/
http://blogs.citrix.com/2011/07/12/xenserver-self-service-manager-beta/

As for XenCenter access controls, you can assign different users to different permission levels, but you can't specify access on a VM level.

This KB article lists all the possible role permissions: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX126442